# Heroku operational error

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, migration

I have an app currently running in Heroku, but it suddenly stopped working, at first it told me I couldn't migrate my DB because some tables that already existed, in fact existed, let me explain myself:

I created a week ago a new table I've been using since, but suddenly, when I tried yesterday to upload a new table, it told me that it couldn't migrate the DB because the table from the last week did exist.

Ok, that was a problem but not the problem it made me ask here, what made me ask here is that, when I was trying to solve that problem, I did this:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'http://url.dump' --app my-app --confirm my-app
```

After that, what my app tells me is this:

```
OperationalError at /
FATAL:  role "ossjuwrohpnfsy" is not permitted to log in
```

I have no idea what "ossjuwrohpnfsy" is or where it comes from, in fact, I've searched for it in my app thought is a really strange name, but, as I though, it doesn't exist in my app

Please, if any of you can tell what is happening or how to solve it you'll save me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely did not promote your new database. See the guide here: [Using PG Backups to Upgrade Heroku Postgres Databases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups)

Essentially:

```
$ heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR -a my-app
```